# Extract numbers from cells containing mixed alpha-numeric text

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I have one column that looks like this:

```
                              A

 1. Dimensions: Width: 23"Depth: 26"Height: 28"Seating Height: 14"
 2. Dimensions: Width: 46"Depth: 26"Height: 28"Seating Height: 14"
```

[image: cell]

[image: sheet]

How can I find out only numeric data in A1 & A2?

I am using Microsoft Excel 2013, and would like to have the output look like this

```
       A    

 1. 23,26,28,14
 2. 46,26,28,14
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use free regex [add-in](http://www.codedawn.com/excel-add-ins.php) which adds regular expression functionality in Excel, with that you get functions with regex:

`=RegExReplace(RegExReplace(A1,"(\D)+",","),",?(.*[^,]),?","$1")`

- inner function converts non numbers to `,`
- outer function removes accidental leading and trailing `,`s

[image]

Comment: Sorry if i have used this function in 2013 so its not work please suggest.

Comment: I'm using it with Excel 2013, also used with 2010 and works with both. Please explain how exactly it doesn't work.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/raHMh.png please check link

Comment: what is the list separator in your regional settings? you may need to use `;` instead of `,`

Comment: If input of 25.0ʺW × 40.0ʺD × 36.0ʺH
28.5ʺW × 33.5ʺD × 37.0ʺH
and i have need output of.
25.0,40.0,36.0
28.5,33.5,37.0

Answer (score 0):

The following will do it with a formula:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(TEXTJOIN("",FALSE,IF((CODE(MID(A1,SEQUENCE(1,LEN(A1)),1))>43)*(CODE(MID(A1,SEQUENCE(1,LEN(A1)),1))<58),MID(A1,SEQUENCE(1,LEN(A1)),1)," ")))," ",","),".,",". ")
```

Easier now that we have `TEXTJOIN()` and `SEQUENCE()` but the uses of both can readily be achieved with the old standbys.

Using `AND()` to put the two tests together seems to kill the internal arrays needed so I changed to the old style `{array of TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,etc.} * {array of TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,etc.}` approach. Checking one condition, then using the result nested in a check for the other condition would be a way too, but this is simpler.

Note that traditionally, one adds a `*1` to make the arrays contain 1's and 0's instead of TRUE/FALSE, but the result is being used by an `IF()` so converting isn't necessary. (And... er... for a second reason, doing the calculation actually converts them without the need for `*1` anyway.)

Little bit of brute force at the end with the `SUBSTITUTE()`'s. Can't slip the spaces out with `TEXTJOIN()` since that'd lose the clear separation of multi-digit number values before spacing them with commas.

As set, it will preserve `","`, `"-"`, and `"."` characters as well as numerical ones, but if `","` or `"-"` is not desired, change the first `CODE()` value's test to >44 or >45.